# OR query in eWAM - picker

Tags: search, ewam

So in a picker in eWam / wynsure the field usually gets passed directly to some sort of OQL statement.

Hence, if I want to search for a field whose value ends in "asdf", I enter "%asdf" into the picker field.

My question is thus:  from the picker, is there anyway to specify 'I want all entries that end in "asdf" OR "qwer"'?

If not, I would recommend that this become a feature as it would be very useful to be able to enter all that right in the text field.

Comment: I am aware that when creating a picker you can place several fields on the scenario and then pass those text values to the OQL statement in such a way as to simulate an OR search... but that is not exactly what I am asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no way to search multiple strings in a single field beyond using wildcards. One can do this easily by creating multiple fields in the picker.

Alternatively one could customize the picker as follows:

1. use a presearch string (that the user fills out),
2. parse that string for some element (like a pipe),
3. Break the string up and put each part in to off screen search variables.

You are still using multiple fields, but the user get's a different experience. Keep in mind the dangers of parsing out the user input, using something like or would work out very badly splitting up words, & could show up in a company name...